# Intellij Differences Viewer to compare three branches

Tags: git, intellij-idea, branching-and-merging

I need to compare 3 different branches. How to perform with standard Intellij Diffeferences Viewer?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this in the current version of IDEA, you can only compare two.

For two branches you can do:

> VCS → Git → Compare with branch

Comment: To compare the entire branch, use Compare action from the branches pop-up. It is only possible to compare current branch with selected.